# PHP Array with images and text

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller

I am trying to display an Image in a PHP Array.
So basicly what I've got:

View:

```
<?php
    include "controllers/Autos.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        foreach($mercedesRood as $value){
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

include "models/autos.php";

$mercedesRood = array('image' => "$mercedesRoodImage","$mercedesRoodKleur","$mercedesRoodMerk");

class Autos extends Controller{
    
}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php

    $mercedesRoodImage = ("./libs/MercedesRood.jpg");
    $mercedesRoodMerk = "Mercedes";
    $mercedesRoodKleur = "Rood";

    $bmwZwartImage = ("./libs/BmwZwart.jpg");
    $bmwZwartMerk = ("BMW");
    $bmwZwartKleur = ("Zwart");
?>
```

Right now it's a string but I need to convert the string to an URL.
(Yes, my .htacces is set correctly because I tested it before by just using the variable and not the array.)

Comment: just echo <img src="$value">? Probably fix the path and you should output an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the array in your controller with indexes. Like this:

```
<?php

include "models/autos.php";

$mercedesRood = array(   
    'image' => $mercedesRoodImage, 
    'color' => $mercedesRoodKleur, 
    'brand' => $mercedesRoodMerk
);
```

Next, you can show the images within the view, using that index:

```
<?php
    include "controllers/Autos.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo '<img src="'.$mercedesRood['image'].'">';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php for more information about array's.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. It was very helpful. I did come across several posts that are similar to what you wrote. What I actually meant was to output the text and image with 1 variable. I already got with some luck how to do that. But then I thought that it wouldn't be really usefull if it was all in 1 variable. So this is still very helpfull <3